# how to achieve the effect like this page,showing apply at the bottom all the time?

Tags: html, css

http://jobview.monster.com/Pearle-Vision-Sales-Associate-Job-Fairview-IL-US-82910211.aspx

Should be cross browser

Answer (score 1):

[Fixed positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_class_position.asp). You need a [Javascript hack](http://tagsoup.com/cookbook/css/fixed/) to get it working in IE6.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://web-kreation.com/demos/Sliding_login_panel_jquery/) is a demo of what you want using JQuery. There is also a link to how to do it using Mootools. Click on Login to see the panel drop.